# Get Websocket URL from Node js

Tags: node.js, websocket

I am trying to build a simple WebSockets app with node.js as a server. In order to create a WebSocket connection I write:

```
const url = 'ws://localhost:8080'
const connection = new WebSocket(url)
```

But I do not want to hardcode the URL. Can I receive it from my server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Available options:

- Using of Webpack/Rollup/Snowpack - https://dev.to/sanfra1407/how-to-use-env-file-in-javascript-applications-with-webpack-18df:

  - You can define a some `.env` and define address of server
  - Use `dotenv` or something another library on backend side to receive variable
  - Use Webpack/Rollup/Snowpack on frontend side to build frontend with defined address of server
  - It will allow to change address of server in one place
- SSR (server-side rendering) - https://medium.com/jspoint/a-beginners-guide-to-react-server-side-rendering-ssr-bf3853841d55

  - You can provide address of server from backend to frontend